# How do I run execute commands from a file?

Tags: java, linux, terminal

How do I execute commands by running a file in Linux? I need to run the following commands:

```
cd /bin
java -cp main
```

What should the file extension be?

Comment: It could be any extension but the convention (in bash) is to use `.sh` (and make the file executable, of course...)

Comment: Use `ProcessBuilder`, it will allow you to define the execution context (directory) from which the command should be executed, for [example](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/28955020/compiling-and-executing-using-exec-in-java-fails-using-command-that-works-from-t/28955036#28955036) and [example](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15218892/running-a-java-program-from-another-java-program/15220419#15220419)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

### Welcome to bash scripting.

What you want to achieve, is one of the **most important features** of any terminal, to execute commands from a file.

In Linux, you need not have any particular extension for a bash file, although the `.sh` extension is customary.

Create a file with any name, (I'll choose `script.sh`)

The contents:

```
#!/bin/bash
cd /bin
java -cp main
```

Make it executable now:

```
$ chmod a+x script.sh
```

Now execute the script:

```
$ ./script.sh
```

Voila! Your first bash script. You can learn more about bash scripting [here](http://tldp.org/HOWTO/Bash-Prog-Intro-HOWTO.html).

#### EDIT:

Since the OP is running Raspian Wheezy, [this](http://www.raspberry-projects.com/pi/pi-operating-systems/raspbian/scripts) can help him create scripts.

Comment: When I try to execute it I get "bash: ./start.sh: Permission denied."

Comment: Did you do `chmod a+x start.sh`?

Comment: Yes. It just won't let me execute it.

Comment: Which distro are you running?

Comment: Raspian "Wheezy" www.raspberrypi.org

Comment: Try `sudo chmod 755 start.sh`.

Answer (score 0):

[Running linux commands in java:](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3403226/how-to-run-linux-commands-in-java-code)

Doing this is possible with java.

Runtime.exec() method should work for you.

Write a shell script file and invoke it from the java code like this...

```
{
   Process pro = Runtime.getRuntime().exec("./script.sh");                        
   pro.waitFor();
}
```

The script that you create contains your desired command by following the bash introduction given in the other answer.