# How to run java program inside another java program

Tags: java, minecraft, bukkit

I want to know how can I run a another java console application (jar1) inside another java application (jar2) also I want to be able to see jar1 outputs and insert my own inputs from jar2.

Let me explain more. there is a program called spigot (see more in www.spigotmc.org): Spigot is CLI java program for running a minecraft server 
and you have to run it with launch flags in a bat file in windows server like:
`java -Xmx 1024m -Xms 1024Xms spigot.jar1`. Now I want to make a program which let me to running this on my own graphical design not in a console.

How can I pass arguments to an existing command window?

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15218892/running-a-java-program-from-another-java-program

Comment: but i need lunch flags too inside my program. i cant see any lunch flag in this

Answer (score 1):

Run a new program with [`ProcessBuilder`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/lang/ProcessBuilder.html). You cannot modify arguments in any already running program, so terminate them first.

Comment: Could you give an example? Also, can you pass commands/arguments after you ran the builder? Because you enter your commands in the constructor, and that's the only time the show up :/

Comment: `ProcessBuilder` is used to run a new program, I'm not sure what's ambiguous about it. An example is already in the documentation within it and any I give would be less accurate than the official demo.